# Wordpress homepage banner not appearing

Tags: wordpress

My homepage banner image is not appearing. I have done some troubleshooting:
1. I noticed on the back-end in visual composer that the revolution slider block had been deleted. I have re-added it, but its still not working
2. I have checked the revolution slider plugin but all appears ok
3. I have updated all plugins
4. I also noticed on the homepage that the 'Blog' post thumbnails aren't showing up either. the heading is there but the 3 latest blog posts are missing.

Maybe it is something to do with visual composer?

Can anyone suggest any other troubleshooting tips?

Website is: 
www.skinmade.com.au

Comment: Show us your code: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have been using visual composer, so not 100% sure if this is the correct code: "home-main" is the name of the revolution slider i created.            [vc_row][vc_column][rev_slider_vc alias="home-main"][vc_row_inner][vc_column_inner][vc_column_text]
<p style="font-size: 30px; text-align: center;">S o f t  .  C l e a n  .  N a t u r a l</p>

<div class="page" title="Page 1">
<div class="layoutArea">
<div class="column">
<p style="font-size: 30px; text-align: center;">Nourishing skincare for beautiful skin. No animal testing. No toxins.</p>

</div>
</div>
</div>